# Convert a DStream to JavaDStream

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I know we have an option for `RDD`:

```
JavaRDD<String> javaRDD = coreRdd.toJavaRDD();`
```

is it possible to convert Dstream to JavaDStream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the static [`JavaDStream<T>.fromDStream`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/api/java/JavaDStream.html#fromDStream(org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag)):

```
JavaDStream<String> javaDStream = 
   JavaDStream$.MODULE$.fromDStream(dStream,
                                    scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(String.class))
```

Another option would be to use the class constructor, which takes an existing `DStream`:

```
JavaDStream<String> javaDStream = 
   new JavaDStream<String>(dStream, scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(String.class))
```

Comment: I'm getting the following exception. "JavaDStream cannot be resolved to a variable". My java version is 8 and spark version 1.6.1...

Comment: @Balaji Did you copy and paste this example? Seems like you're not calling it correctly.

Comment: Yes I copy pasted it. But the problem here is JavaDStream<T>.fromDStream is not static as you mentioned. I twicked it with your input. Please check my answer and give me your valuable thought.

Comment: JavaDStream$ cannot be resolved. t getting tis comp. error @Yuval

Comment: @BalajiReddy Did you `import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream$;`?

Comment: Cool. I tried auto import form my eclipse but it din happen. I added the import manually , now it works .