# Apache Spark Java APIs limitations

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Can someone provide me some sample Java APIs that are yet to be implemented in Apache Spark.I am trying to see if there are any Scala Spark APIs that "do not exist/have limited functionality" if I decide to use the Java APIs rather.
That would be a deal-breaker for me.

Disclaimer:
Based on my googling/analysis I realize that Scala community support for Apache Spark is really good.Also I understand that in order to work efficiently with Spark you need to learn some Scala anyway(As source code is in Scala).

Answer (score 1):

### Optimistic point of view:

[Consider that](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/faq/4):

> The standard Scala backend is a Java VM. Scala classes are Java classes, and vice versa. You can call the methods of either language from methods in the other one. You can extend Java classes in Scala, and vice versa. The main limitation is that some Scala features do not have equivalents in Java, for example traits.

Conclusion - there is no missing API

### Pessimistic point of view:

Spark is written in Scala has Scala-centric API and is not Java friendly. There multiple packages (like GraphX) which have no Java friendly API. You need code [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38411201/6022341) once in a while.

Comment: Thanks, this helps!!I know that there are some limitations with types(Java).
For example Tuple doesn't have a built in type for Java and there is a work-around(Tuple2) to handle that.

Any other types if you are aware of that would help as well.